# Can I combine these two Express routes?

Tags: node.js, express

In other words, how can I combine the paths '/' and '/:id'?

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Text.find().sort( { created_at: -1 } ).limit(10).exec(function (err, texts) { 
        parseTexts(err, texts, req, res);
    });
});

app.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Text.find( { user: req.params.id } ).sort( { created_at: -1 } ).limit(10).exec(function (err, texts) { 
        parseTexts(err, texts, req, res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (note- untested)

```
app.get('/:id?', function(req, res) {
    if(req.params.id) {
        Text.find( { user: req.params.id } ).sort( { created_at: -1 } ).limit(10).exec(function (err, texts) { 
            parseTexts(err, texts, req, res);
        });
    }
    else {
        Text.find().sort( { created_at: -1 } ).limit(10).exec(function (err, texts) { 
            parseTexts(err, texts, req, res);
        });
    }
});
```

Could probably refactor your query some more....

Comment: How would you refactor the query?